# Enumerated values with a single array of numbers without looping

Tags: enumerate

I am writing some functionality for a visual node based CAD program that will not allow for me to loop so I need a workaround to enumerate a list of numbers. I am an architect with very little programming experience so any help would be great.

A have an array of numbers(numArray) coming in as such 0,1,2,3,4... (first column) I need to take those numbers and convert them into their counterpart for column 1,2,3,4 without using any loops or nested loops.

```
   numArray 1 2 3 4
        -----------
        0 = 0|0|0|0
        1 = 0|0|0|1
        2 = 0|0|0|2
        3 = 0|0|0|3
        4 = 0|0|1|0
        5 = 0|0|1|1
        6 = 0|0|1|2
        7 = 0|0|1|3
        8 = 0|0|2|0
        9 = 0|0|2|1
        10= 0|0|2|2
        12= 0|0|2|3
        13= 0|0|3|0
        14= 0|0|3|1
        15= 0|0|3|2
        16= 0|1|3|3
        17= 0|1|0|0
        18= 0|1|0|1
        19= 0|1|0|2
        20= 0|1|0|3
        21= 0|1|1|0
        22= 0|1|1|1
        23= 0|1|1|2
        24= 0|1|1|3
```

I have figured out column 4 by implementing the following:

```
int column4 = numArray % 4;
```

this works and creates the numbers as such 0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3.... this is great however I am not sure how to use the num array coming in to produce column 3 2 and 1. Again I have very little programming experience so any help would be great.

Comment: This appears to be just counting in base 4, but I'm not really clear on the nature of your input data.  Could you provide a brief example of the actual input?  

Also, since your solution for column 4 is expressed in C syntax, can I assume this post needs a C tag?

Comment: The input would be the first column of numbers above which is constant, always starting at 0 and counting to lets say 1000 like so (0,1,2,3,4...) the other 4 columns are the values that I need to return. For example when the input number is 6, I need var1 = 0, var2= 0, var 3 = 1, var 4 = 2 and so on. I am able to produce column 4 with the mod operator but I am not sure how to use the input data to produce columns 1,2 and 3. Technically this is in C# but I used C like syntax just to get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're converting the input to base 4 notation, so this will do the job:

```
int input[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24};

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(input)/sizeof(input[0]); i++)
{
    int c1, c2, c3, c4;

    c4 = input[i] % 4;
    c3 = (input[i] / 4) % 4;
    c2 = (input[i] / 16) % 4;
    c1 = (input[i] / 64) % 4;

    printf("%d = %d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", input[i], c1, c2, c3, c4);
}
```

Comment: You're welcome.  I hope you understand why this works for base 4 and how you could adapt it to base 8, 16, 19... any base.